# NGINX: ssl proxy based on path to multiple apps on localhost with different ports

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx to proxy requests to different servers running on the host machine with different ports depending on request path. To complicate things a bit more, I want all the apps to use ssl. In other words I want nginx to do the following:

```
https://www.example.com/app1 --> http://localhost:8001
https://www.example.com/app2 --> http://localhost:8002
https://www.example.com/app3 --> http://localhost:8003
...
```

What I got so far (which is not quite working):

```
# redirecting from http to https
server {
    listen 80;
    301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# proxying path to port
server {
    listen 443;
    ssl_certificate     /path/to/cert.pem
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.pem
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location /app1 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001
    }
    location /app2 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8002
    }
    location /app3 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8003
    }
}
```

What ends up happening is that nginx only exposes one specific app (that was there first).

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So if you browser `/app3` first it works and rest won't work? What goes wrong?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, yes, only (e.g.) `/app3` works and when I try `https://www.example.com/app1` it says cannot GET `.../app1`. Also, when I try `https://www.example.com/` it shows `/app3`.

Comment: Is it possible for you apps to work like `http://localhost:8001/app1`, because I am afraid your approach cannot work and would become complicated if the apps themselves work on the root directory

Comment: I suppose that for some apps mount path is configurable but I wouldn't count on that in the most general case. So, is my approach just complicated or wouldn't work with nginx?

Comment: One issue i can see is the missing trailing `/`. Change things to `location /app1/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/;
    }` This will make sure that `/app1` doesn't go to `http://localhost:8001/` as a part of the request url

Comment: I've tried this before and it doesn't change the described behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154259/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-alexander-f).

Comment: Is your ssl path right? and please curl apps running on perticular ports. If you run your nginx in container it doesn't work with localhost/loopback 127.0.0.1:port, use private ip instead.

Comment: @JinnaBalu, my SSL path is correct and I'm not running nginx in a container. Some of the apps may be running inside docker containers (with appropriate port publishing of course)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your nginc.conf with the following

```
    server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;
      server_name _;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
      listen 443;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;

      ssl on;
      ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/ssl/demo.com.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/ssl/demo.com.key;

      ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";      

      chunked_transfer_encoding on;

      location /app1 {
         proxy_pass http://<private-ip>:8001
      }
      location /app2 {
         proxy_pass http://<private-ip>:8002
      }
      location /app3 {
         proxy_pass http://<private-ip>:8003
      }

    }
```

Copy your .crt, .kry file in your required folder

Comment: Jinna, can you give some explanation why what you say should work and why what I do doesn't? Thanks.